# ffmpeg installation error

Tags: ffmpeg

Now that I'm down to the last part to install the FFMPEG it tells me to do the following

```
cd /usr/local/src/ffmpeg/

./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared
make
make install

ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.50 /usr/lib/libavformat.so.50
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.51 /usr/lib/libavcodec.so.51
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavutil.so.49 /usr/lib/libavutil.so.49
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.so.0 /usr/lib/libmp3lame.so.0
ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavformat.so.51 /usr/lib/libavformat.so.51
```

When I get to the part

```
./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libogg --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared
```

I get the error

```
Unknown option "--enable-libogg".
See ./configure --help for available options.
```

I've tried removing the `--enable-libogg` but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Does ./configure --help  help? It should show you if this is valid.
What errors do you get when you removed this option?

Comment: This is a question better addressed to http://stackoverflow.com/. One thing that comes to mind, is that you need to write the ./configure line yourself, there might be some problem with copypaste characters.

Comment: @tstm, I disagree. It is not about programming, which is the domain of StackOverflow. I'd suggest http://SuperUser.com/ is more suitable, but that might be splitting hairs.

Answer (score 1):

First, which version of FFmpeg are you trying to build?  [0.5.1](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), or from Git or Subversion?

Assuming it is version 0.5.1, `--enable-libogg` is not a configure flag, so I don't know why you think you need it. In fact other than `--enable-libmp3lame` I'm not sure why you have those flags specified. In particular `--disable-mmx` strikes me as odd.

So in other words. Build it without the `--enable-libogg` flag. It doesn't appear to need it.

---

**Added:**

I tried `./configure --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libamr-nb --enable-libamr-wb --enable-libvorbis --disable-mmx --enable-shared --enable-nonfree` and it worked with version ffmpeg-0.5.1.

I don't know what else to say.